# highlight jtable row fro past due date reminder

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, jcalendar

This is employee data information. I have the contact starting date and expiration date, so I want to know how I can highlight a row in the jtable if there is a contact that will expire in one month or less.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) after that, learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and finally post a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste. That way you'll get more, better and faster answers, and you'll be demonstrating that you have already tried something instead of just asking for code :)

Comment: See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of `Table` to highlight the entire row based on the data in the row:

```
JTable table = new JTable( model )
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if (!isRowSelected(row))
        {
            Date date = getModel().getValueAt(row, ???);

            if (date expires in one month)
                c.setBackground( someColor );
            else
                c.setBackground( getBackground() );
        }

        return c;
    }
};
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for some working examples.